# NestJS Hot Module Replacement: Invalid options object

Tags: webpack, nestjs, webpack-hmr

I am using NestJS and am trying to install Hot Module replacement, following this page's instructions: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload

Since I am using Nest CLI, I followed the first part of the page. However, at the moment I have to use the `nest build --webpack --webpackPath webpack-hmr.config.js` command, I get the following error:

```
Error  Invalid options object. Watch Ignore Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options[0] misses the property 'paths'. Should be:
   [RegExp | string, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
   -> A list of RegExps or absolute paths to directories or files that should be ignored.
 - options[1] misses the property 'paths'. Should be:
   [RegExp | string, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
   -> A list of RegExps or absolute paths to directories or files that should be ignored.
```

Does anyone know where that could come from and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue comes from the update from webpack 4 to webpack 5: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5667

There are 2 solutions:

- Wait for `start-server-webpack-plugin` to update and not use HMR in the mean time
- Downgrade to webpack 4